# Assistance with a JSON dump in application

Tags: jquery, ruby, json, twitter, sinatra

I was wondering if anyone could help explain a few things with what is going on in the following scenario. I am trying to grab all my Tweets using the new twitter api v.1.1. I come across [this](http://thisbythem.com/blog/simple-sinatra-for-twitter-api-pie-guy-fieri/) blog post showing how to do using sinatra. So i have set this up and get a JSON dump of my tweets at localhost:9393/feed

```
get '/feed' do
 jsonp @@twitter_client.user_timeline('richl14').map(&:attrs)
end
```

My first question is what is the @@ doing, second question is how can i get the tweets to show up on my index page...Using jQuery? If someone could provide a simple example that would help me a lot

JSON Structure

```
 [
{
"created_at": "Thu Jun 13 10:56:45 +0000 2013",
"id": 345132629995184128,
"id_str": "345132629995184128",
"text": "@phoenix_touch You guys need any new players? Looking to pop down next week.",
"source": "web",
"truncated": false,
"in_reply_to_status_id": null,
"in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
"in_reply_to_user_id": 576324146,
"in_reply_to_user_id_str": "576324146",
"in_reply_to_screen_name": "phoenix_touch",
"user": {
  "id": 383286861,
  "id_str": "383286861",
  "name": "Richard Lewis",
  "screen_name": "richl14",
  "location": "United kingdom",
  "description": "#RubyonRails #webdev #softwaretesting #Newport #Wales",
  "url": null,
  "entities": {
    "description": {
      "urls": [

      ]
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable prefixed with `@@` is a *class variable*. This is a variable that is set on an entire Ruby class, instead of on a single instance (`@` prefix) or locally (no prefix).

To access the feed in jQuery, try something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $container = $('#container');

    $.get('/feed', function(data) {
        $container.empty();
        $.each(data.tweets, function(_, tweet) {
            var $tweet = $(document.createElement('div'));
            $tweet.text(tweet.contents);
            $container.append($tweet);
        });
    }, 'json');
});
```

This'll work when the feed look like this:

```
{
    "tweets": [
        { "contents": "Hello, World!", "username": "albert" },
        { "contents": "Too many twits might make a twat.",
          "username": "DavidCameron" }
    ]
}
```

You'll have to change to code to accommodate the actual JSON structure, but this is a start.

Comment: thanks very much, 1 more thing, sorry to ask but what is .map(&:attrs) doing and ive added an example of the JSON structure, its a hash right?

Comment: `.map(&:attrs)` runs the `attrs` method for each element of whatever is returned by `user_timeline('richl14')`.